# what is the purpose of art board in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i want to know in details what exactly is the purpose of art board in adobe illustrator?? does it have any important role in printing document?

some one told me if i do not take any white shape (be that circle or rectangle) behind my design it wont be printed. all i will get is 'NOTHING'

is that true?  do i need to place a white rectangle as a background page behind my design?

Thank you.

Comment: From [the Adobe help site](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/artboards-basics.html): "Artboards are similar to pages in Adobe InDesign or Microsoft Word and represent the printable area."

Comment: the artboard is not white. You can see this by enabling transparency grid. You dont need to have white. But you almost certainly need to have an artboard. Anyway, white is same as nothing i most normal print processes. Not having white medium would need either white ink or some unusual equipment. You need to be very careful if you specify white though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question for which there is a lot of reading material and videos available from a simple search for "what is the artboard in Illustrator"
[image]

In general, consider the artboard to be the printable area of your project. The artboard is where you assemble the various assets of your project into the final presentation.

And yes, the artboard is transparent initially. (You can see this by going to View> Show Transparency Grid). It initially shows as white to simulate printing on white paper. Anything you put on the artboard will print onto whatever color paper you use and that paper will be your background color. If you are not printing your project but using it for some other purpose then yes, you can add a shape behind your work so it has a background shape and color.

Comment: before posting here i surfed .. but all those seems hard. nobody mentions anything about the relation between printing and artboard. you did. thank you so much.